# XSL-FO make text different color in single element

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have searched all morning for an answer to this, with no luck. Maybe I'm just not searching correctly, I don't know. I am displaying XML markup in a PDF using the following tag set:

```
<verbatimText>&lt;para>&lt;quantity>
&lt;quantityGroup quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">&lt;quantityValue>10&lt;/quantityValue>
&lt;quantityTolerance quantityToleranceType="plusorminus" quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">  2&lt;/quantityTolerance>&lt;/quantityGroup>
&lt;/quantity>.&lt;/para></verbatimText>
```

I have no issue displaying this as an all **BOLD**, single color block in the PDF. What I want to try and accomplish is to make the XML syntax colored, much like syntax highlighting in a text editor, where the element names would be blue, the attributes red, and element content black.

I would think there is a way to format substrings of text, but am having trouble finding a good starting spot on this one.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: No, I am running the XSL transform through FOP, which last I knew did not support 2.0.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't separate the xslt transform from the fo processing?

Comment: Short answer, probably not. My XSLT now results in an FO doc. What would be your recommendation if I were to use two different transforms to get to the final FO? Would I not then need to write a second XSL doc to finish my transform? Forgive me if I looking at this too short-sightedly.

Comment: You wouldn't have to have a second XSLT. What I'm suggesting is transforming your XML to XSL-FO (with your XSLT) using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon. Then processing the XSL-FO file with FOP. I always separate my XSLT (XML->XSL-FO) from the processing of the XSL-FO file.

Comment: OK, but in doing so, what would you recommend as the process to color the text substrings I am after? I'm not sure what to use from 2.0 to get where I want be. If I go this route of running to FO in one transform, and then to FOP in a second operation, I could use Java or some/any other language to find and select the substrings and surround them with <fo:inline color="..."></fo:inline>

Comment: I will try to add an example of what I would do soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could use XSLT 2.0 (`xsl:analyze-string`) to add color.

It could use some tweaking, but illustrates what I was thinking...

**XML Input**

```
<verbatimText>&lt;para>&lt;quantity>
&lt;quantityGroup quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">&lt;quantityValue>10&lt;/quantityValue>
&lt;quantityTolerance quantityToleranceType="plusorminus" quantityUnitOfMeasure="ft.lbf">  2&lt;/quantityTolerance>&lt;/quantityGroup>
&lt;/quantity>.&lt;/para></verbatimText>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="verbatimText">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(&lt;/?)([^\s>]+)(>?)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <fo:inline color="#0000FF"><xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(1),'&#xFEFF;',regex-group(2),
                        if (regex-group(3)) then '&#xFEFF;>' else '')"/></fo:inline>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\s)([^=&lt;]+=['&quot;])([^'&quot;]+)(['&quot;])(>?)">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                            <fo:inline color="#FF0000"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></fo:inline>
                            <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/>
                            <fo:inline color="#FF0000"><xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(4),
                                if (regex-group(5)) then '&#xFEFF;>' else '')"/></fo:inline>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>                            
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO** (Using Saxon-HE 9.5)

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>
            <fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;﻿para﻿&gt;</fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;﻿quantity﻿&gt;</fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;﻿quantityGroup</fo:inline> 
            <fo:inline color="#FF0000">quantityUnitOfMeasure="</fo:inline>ft.lbf<fo:inline color="#FF0000">"﻿&gt;</fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;﻿quantityValue﻿&gt;</fo:inline>10<fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;/﻿quantityValue﻿&gt;</fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;﻿quantityTolerance</fo:inline> 
            <fo:inline color="#FF0000">quantityToleranceType="</fo:inline>plusorminus<fo:inline color="#FF0000">"</fo:inline> 
            <fo:inline color="#FF0000">quantityUnitOfMeasure="</fo:inline>ft.lbf<fo:inline color="#FF0000">"﻿&gt;</fo:inline>  2<fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;/﻿quantityTolerance﻿&gt;</fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;/﻿quantityGroup﻿&gt;</fo:inline>
            <fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;/﻿quantity﻿&gt;</fo:inline>.<fo:inline color="#0000FF">&lt;/﻿para﻿&gt;</fo:inline>
         </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**PDF Output** (Using FOP 1.1)

[image]

Comment: This is terrific. I needed to get brushed up on my regex in order to completely understand the filters you used (kinda ashamed to say I don't know it). The only thing I changed is that the the closing '>' after an attribute was colored red and made it blue.

Comment: @twfurst - I didn't catch those > being red. Glad my example helped.